# determine if column value string starts with a number

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `Questions` with a column `Description`. Its column values are like this:

```
This is First Heading, 
1 This is Subheading one, 
1.2 This is subheading Question
This is Second heading
2 This is subheading Two.
2.1 This is Subheading Question1
```

How can I determine, for each row, if its column value starts with a number 0-9?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(Description), 1, 1)) = 1 
         THEN 'yes' 
         ELSE 'no' 
       END AS StartsWithNumber
FROM Questions
```

- [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)
- [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187748%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 16):

```
SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Description LIKE '[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  the following query. Which first remove extra space form the left side and get first left character. This query return 0 if it is not numeric other wise it return 1.

```
Select ISNUMERIC(Left(Ltrim('1 This is Subheading'),1)) As Number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select true where cast(substring('1 This is Subheading', 1, 1) as int) between 0 AND 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from TABLE_NAME 
where (YourColName like '0%' or 
       YourColName like '1%' or 
       YourColName like '2%' or 
       YourColName like '3%' or 
       YourColName like '4%' or 
       YourColName like '5%' or 
       YourColName like '6%' or 
       YourColName like '7%' or 
       YourColName like '8%' or 
       YourColName like '9%')
```