# How to retrieve column data that starts with only number access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a column which contains data starting with letters and numbers. In order to retrieve only data starts which starts with a digit, how to specify in a query?

Comment: Is the length of potential numeric data fixed or can it be any length?

Comment: Also, see this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539141/microsoft-office-access-like-vs-regex) which is not an exact duplicate but is very, very close to what you're asking.

Comment: I think this should help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243852/determine-if-column-value-string-starts-with-a-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `LIKE` pattern match.

```sql
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourColumn LIKE '[0-9]*'
```

If you will be running the query from ADO, or with OleDb from outside an Access session, use `%` instead of `*` as the wild card character.

```sql
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourColumn LIKE '[0-9]%'
```

Or you could substitute `ALIKE` for `LIKE` and then the query will always run the same regardless of where and how you run it.

```sql
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourColumn ALIKE '[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE YourColumn LIKE '[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]*'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!